# The Flutter Directory Is Not A Clone of GitHub Project

Tags: flutter

I had downloaded **Flutter** from https://flutter.io/setup-windows/ (flutter_windows_v0.5.1-beta.zip)
in windows 10 and followed the guidelines, extracted the zip in **C:\Users\M. Junaid** and opened flutter-console.bat. I tried to run flutter doctor but got the following

```
Error: The Flutter directory is not a clone of the GitHub project.
       The flutter tool requires Git in order to operate properly;
       The to set up flutter, run the following command:
       git clone -b beta https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
```

[image: Flutter Error]

**Re-checked the dependencies Git and PowerShell which are correctly installed and path variable is also correct - C:\Users\M.Junaid\flutter\bin**

I Tried These But Nothing Worked:

1. Tried to extract in different locations C:\flutter, in AppData etc.
2. Running flutter_console.bat as administrator.
3. cd flutter and then running the command

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Flutter checks for a git folder, which is normally a hidden folder.  If you copied and pasted the contents of the zip file, there is a good chance that you missed copying this hidden folder.

You can solve this by doing one of the following:

1. Unzip the folder directly to where you want Flutter, or
2. Copy the outer folder (`flutter`) to include all the hidden files inside, or
3. Show all hidden files before selecting them and copying.

Comment: If you are using mac, you can see hidden files and folders by using command + shift + . The solution suggested here solved the problem...

Comment: I used the `mv` command to move the content, and by default hidden files are not moved.
So, I had to check my Trash, and restore the content. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I solved this by using this command:

```
git clone -b beta https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
```

(Note: make sure you have git installed.)

After that, try to open `flutter_console.bat` and type any flutter command to check whether it is installed properly or not.

Answer (score 7):

I was having this problem even using git to download it.
The solution was to change the folder name from .github to .git
In windows I did the following.

```
rename .github .git
```

Comment: This worked for me, I included flutter as a subtree in my gitlab project and had the same error and renaming .github to .git worked

Answer (score 5):

you need to run 
`git init` 
so that the .git folder can be created.
once you do that flutter doctor will work as intended.

Comment: you saved my day :D it was only the beginning and I was already blocked here... thank you

Answer (score 2):

The flutter script checks whether there is a `.git` directory in the working directory. If this directory is not in place, then the message is seen as reported.

So double-check for the presence of this directory. If it is not there, you may need to re-clone the repository.

Answer (score 1):

This mistake also raises when flutter has '!' in a file path. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26571

So you need to rename a folder with '!' in its name.

Worked for me, while other solution didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with Flutter 1.0. I solved it by running the following command:

```
git clean -xfd
```

This deletes all existing files and re-creates them again in another folder.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you might forget some **hidden files** like below (Github project does have *.git* directory), when you copy/move extracted content from *flutter_windows_v0.5.1-beta.zip* to  *C:\Users\M. Junaid*.

```
.cirrus.yml
.codecov.yml
.git
.gitattributes
.github
.gitignore
.idea
.pub-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

1- delete old flutter folder sdk, unzip the fresh version

2- Open the unzip folder of flutter sdk, then check the files hidden of ".git" to be visible, by runing command of visible the files , by open termnail and cd to path of folder :

defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles true